# copy some vertices UV location and transfer it to another UV Map

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, uv

So i got my hands on these models rip from a video game created from the unreal engine but when converting the files it created 4 UV Maps for the same object each  map was made for a different texture and now trying to assign the different Material to the object is creating but i don't want to remap one uv map if it's already in a different one 
here are the different uv maps with the texture it post to be on

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYM2U.jpg here are the pics

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

ok now this is the face in each uv map all of the vertex that are not being used are put at x:0 y:0

Comment: you may separate the mesh by material. Then keep only the good UV map and material for each part. Rename the UV map 'UV map' for all. Then merge them again